# Deleting the item from the WEB database when the item unpublish date and time is over

Tags: sitecore-api

I have an item. I select the Date and time for that item to unpublish(MASTER). When the date and time passes, I switch to the web database and I still see that item there. We have a service that calls the web database to get some data. The problem I am having is that item is still  present in the  web database even the date and time as passed to unpublish it. How can I delete the item in the WEB database when the item is unpublished after the date and time. Sitecore ver 8.2

The pic with Date and time is the MASTER and pic without anything is the WEB

[image]

[image]

Comment: The schedule that runs is not exactly at the time that you put. There's an agent that runs That's some frequency. Perhaps what you're missing is the publishing agent isn't doing what you think it should.

Comment: The scheduled job runs every 5 mins. Did you publish the page after you sent the unpublished date and time? A republish that that item should remove it from web db.

Comment: Can you see this message "If you publish now, the item will not be visible on the web site as the unpublishing date has been reached." on web ?